# Update Date Sorting Alternative

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift3

I am currently trying to update the code for a Udemy course I purchased a couple of months ago, which was fully working in the Swift 2.2 version. However, I am having issues with this particular function, which really just sorts and displays recent chats (with preview).

Here is the code:

```
 func loadRecents() {
        firebase.child("Recent").queryOrderedByChild("userId").queryEqualToValue(backendless.userService.currentUser.objectId).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: {
            snapshot in

            self.recents.removeAll()

            if snapshot.exists() {

                let sorted = (snapshot.value!.allValues as NSArray).sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: false)])

                for recent in sorted {

                    self.recents.append(recent as! NSDictionary)
                    firebase.child("Recent").queryOrderedByChild("chatRoomID").queryEqualToValue(recent["chatRoomID"]).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: {
                        snapshot in
                    })

                }

            }

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })

    }
```

I get the error here:

```
let sorted = (snapshot.value!.allValues as NSArray).sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: false)])
```

I beleive the `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors` is deprecated, but I am still not sure. What could be a replacement of this current code?

Thanks in advance!

Update:

This is the error I am getting:

```
THread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
```

Comment: If you could add the exact error you're receiving from the compiler, this would Increase your chances of getting a correct answer.

Comment: @torinpitchers The answer is updated now. I am getting this error: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Answer (score 0):

The specific answer to the question: what is a replacement (in Swift 3):

```
let sorted = ((snapshot!.value! as AnyObject).allValues as NSArray)
         .sortedArray(using: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: false)])
```

Also, the code posted basically works - although the code inside the *for recent in sorted* section is malformed for Swift 3.

recent["chatRoomID"] in that section may be an issue as the data within *sorted* may not be strings - they may be dictionaries. It depends on your Firebase structure.

Lastly, it's probably a good idea to reduce you're dependency on NSSortDescriptors etc and do it in a more Swifty way.

See my answer to your prior question

[Swift 3 Firebase update code convertion - sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39705363/swift-3-firebase-update-code-convertion-sorting/39711143#39711143)

Comment: Hmm, I see. The code seems to run now, however - it shows multiple 'recent' cells with the same value. Your answer to my previous post - seems to be a bit off, as the structure of the snapshot is [String:AnyObject]. Any idea on how I might make the code for 'recent' not malformed?

Comment: @askaale Actually the answer in the prior is correct based on the structure posted in the answer (which could be [String:AnyObject] or [String: [String:String]] as posted. But, we still don't know the Firebase structure you are working with so AnyObject could literally be any object - a String, Array, Dictionary or even a dictionary of dictionaries. Posting your structure is always helpful. Can you update your question and include your FireBase structure?